# How to redirect a URL with a specific parameter to a URL without one?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

So basically, I am trying to remove a parameter from all URLs within my site.

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com.au/thispage.html?view=form
http://www.mydomain.com.au?view=form
http://www.mydomain.com.au/this-is-a-page.html?view=form
```

I require all the pages above to go to their version without this parameter, such as:

```
http://www.mydomain.com.au/thispage.html
http://www.mydomain.com.au
http://www.mydomain.com.au/this-is-a-page.html
```

The redirect must only occur when `view=form`, and not when `view` is equal to anything else.

Very new to regex and apache, so I am not to sure if this is even possible.

So far I have just been using the following code to point them to a 404, although this has been causing a few problems within webmaster tools:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)view=form(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

In case you want to preserve other query parameters (like `?foo1=bar1&view=form&foo2=bar2`) use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:(.*)&)?view=form(?:(&.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately.. it is redirecting to an extremely weird URL - `http://%24%7Bhttp_host%7D%24%7Brequest_uri%7D/`

Comment: Ah, please replace `$`s with `%`s.

Comment: Still getting that annoying error. Any chance you could make an edit on your answer to fix this up for me?

Comment: I have. Please take a look at my update. You may also need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Clearing the cache did it. Thanks for your help, worked perfectly! The second option you did is preferred since there may be other query parameters hanging around that I would not want to disturb. Thanks :)